# Why do I need to initialize a Cucumber DataTable with a Cucumber DataTable?

Tags: ruby, cucumber

We recently started to drag a very old Rails app up to date (or at least out of obsolescence). One of the changes was an update of Cucumber from 1.3.x to 2.99.

Many of our rspec specs on this app used a helper for loading test data which leveraged `Cucumber::Ast::DataTable`. (The helper declared its own subclass which inherited from `Cucumber::Ast::DataTable`.) This was deprecated, so as suggested, I replaced the inheritance with `Cucumber::MultilineArgument::DataTable`.

The subclass looks like this:

```
class ParsedTable < ::Cucumber::MultilineArgument::DataTable
  def initialize(string)
    super(string.split("\n").map do |line|
      line = line.split('|').map(&:squish)
      line.slice(1, line.length)
    end)
  end
end
```

Then there are a bunch of test helpers which create test data like this (assume "role" is a model we'll be testing against):

```
def create_roles(string)
  table = ParsedTable.new(string)
  table.hashes.each do |hash|
    create :role,
      name: hash['Name'],
      short_name: hash['Short Name'],
      contracted_work_day: hash['Contracted workday in minutes']
  end
end
```

These helpers get called like this:

```
create_roles <<-eos
  | Name      | Contracted workday in minutes |
  | Therapist | 390                           |
eos
```

But when that kind of call goes in, I get `ArgumentError: data must be a Core::Ast::DataTable`. The stack says this exception is from `lib/cucumber/multiline_argument/data_table.rb:93:in 'initialize'` which is the `super` call in the `ParsedTable` definition.

I've been trying to chase this around the Cucumber source and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Looks like you need to pass a `Core::Ast::DataTable` in your call to `super`. Maybe this class is not as deprecated as you think?

Comment: Well, `Core::Ast::DataTable` apparently isn't (wasn't) the same as `Cucumber::Ast::DataTable`. I've worked out that `Cucumber::MultilineArgument::DataTable` expects a `Core::Ast::DataTable` as an argument (instead of the array I've been passing), and it has a class method `from()` which will take an Array and return some flavor of `DataTable`. I'm trying to initialize `ParsedTable` with the output of `Cucumber::MultilineArgument::DataTable#from` but it's not really playing well yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API documentation for Cucumber states that the constructor for Cucumber::MultilineArgument::DataTable takes a `Core::Ast::DataTable` object.

Source: https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/cucumber/Cucumber/MultilineArgument/DataTable#constructor_details

You will need an instance of `Core::Ast::DataTable` rather than custom parsing it from a string.

> Creates a new instance. +raw+ should be an Array of Array of String or an Array of Hash You don't typically create your own DataTable objects - Cucumber will do it internally and pass them to your Step Definitions.

Source: https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/cucumber-core/1.3.1/Cucumber/Core/Ast/DataTable#constructor_details

It looks like cucumber should have already parsed the table as a `Core::Ast::DataTable` object in the step binding, so all you should need to do is pass this along to the constructor of your `ParsedTable` class.

When this isn't available, then you'll need to provide an array of array of strings instead.

Comment: This is reasonable, but the trick is it's not happening in Cucumber steps - it's helper methods setting up test data for rspec, and the tables are coming in strings. (See the `create_roles` method in my third snippet above.)

Answer (score 0):

Greg Burghardt's answer has the right cause for this; the `Cucumber::MultilineArgument::DataTable` class requires a `Core::Ast::DataTable` as an argument, which wasn't true of the old `Cucumber::Ast::DataTable`. (This class in general is a bit of a moving target between Cucumber 1.4.x and the current version.)

In the end I solved this by avoiding the problem. Looking carefully at the methods which used the custom `ParsedTable` class, I saw they didn't really depend on the class, but instead counted on calling `hashes` on each instance. What I needed was something which responded to `hashes` with the appropriate response.

So, rather than subclassing `Cucumber::MultilineArgument::DataTable` simply to get a custom constructor, I replaced the subclass definition with a method which accepted a string, split it into rows, and fed that `Array` of rows to `Cucumber::MultilineArgument::DataTable#from`. That returned an instance of `Cucumber::MultilineArgument::DataTable` which I could call `hashes` on. And that works.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error after I upgrade 'cucumber', '2.4.0' to '8.0.0'

```
uninitialized constant Cucumber::Core::Ast (NameError)
```

Failing code where it tries to initialise a datatable.

```
estimated_calls_data_table = Cucumber::Core::Ast::DataTable.new(estimated_calls_rows_values, nil)
```

Correct code:

```
estimated_calls_data_table = 
Cucumber::Core::Test::DataTable.new(estimated_calls_rows_values)
```

now cucumber uses Test class than Ast to create this table.